# Yii 2 nav widget visible vs accessible

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a yii\bootstrap\Nav, where I have several menu items. One of them is the logout. Consider these two examples.

```
    $menuItems = [
            [
                'label'   => 'Logout ('. Yii::$app->user->identity->username. ')',
                'url'     => ['/site/logout'],
                'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post'],
                'visible' => !Yii::$app->user->isGuest,
            ],
    ]
```

vs

```
if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $menuItems[] = 
                [
                    'label'   => 'Logout ('. Yii::$app->user->identity->username. ')',
                    'url'     => ['/site/logout'],
                    'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post'],
                ];

}
```

My Application crashes with the error for the

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

on the line with Yii::$app->user->identity->username.
I use the second solution which works fine, but can you explain why the code executes bypassing the 'visible' parameter for the first block.

Comment: What happens if you put `false` instead of `!Yii::$app->user->isGuest`?

Comment: I get the same error, it seems that even if it is not visible, it still executes. So if there is no logged in user it throws an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case you check for not a guest and this mean that

```
 Yii::$app->user
```

is a correct objecy  and then you can access to username

in first you use only  the visible menuitem attribute  this as described in doc mean

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-menu.html#$items-detail

> Visible: boolean, optional, whether this menu item is visible.
>   Defaults to true.

this mean that this attribute manage the hide  or show of the menu item. But in this case the code for user remain the same so based on fact that a guest don't crate a proper user object you have the rror for accessi a propert ofr a null object

Comment: Discussing the first case: 
If menu item is not visible, why it cares about the existence of the Yii::$app->user ?

Comment: the code is executed  also if the menu is not visibile .. .. In particular the line .. 'label' => 'Logout ('. Yii :: $ app-> user-> identity-> username. ')', Is executed to determine the label of the item .. even if it does not come Displayed .... hope is clear ..

Answer (score 0):

In your first code block

`Yii::$app->user->identity->username`

change it to

`(Yii::$app->user)?("Logout(".(Yii::$app->user->identity->username.")"):'Login'`

**NOTE:** change `url` accordingly. visibility is not required to configure.

If there is no login user `Yii::$app->user->identity->username` statement cannot return `username` because there is no user identity exist (`Yii::$app->user->identity` is `null`)